# Как объявлять константу перечислимого сложного типа?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Часто нужно объявить сложный перечислимый тип.
Например

```
type
  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond);
```

У каждого элемента перечисления должны быть строковые представления и числовые значения (например). Причем обращаться к ним хотелось бы через точку:

```
mtFirst.StrName, mtSecond.IntValue
```

Причем это должна быть константная информация, задаваемая при написании кода, а не во время исполнения программы.

Не могу придумать оптимальный способ - как это красиво и правильно сделать в Delphi.
Отдельные константы-записи - они не объединены в перечислимый тип.
Константный массив записей - обращаться только по индексу....
Перепробовал кучу решений - все кажутся неоптимальными.

Вот в одном из проектов я сделал так:

```pascal
  TTax = class
  public
    type
      TValue = (txUndefined,  //< по старой схеме (брать из Tax1Code)
                tx20, tx18, tx10, tx20120, tx18118, tx10110, tx0, txNone);
  protected
    class function GetAsFloat(Index: TTax.TValue): Double; static;
    class function GetName(AValue: TTax.TValue): string; static;
    class function GetAsString(AValue: TTax.TValue): string; static;
  public
    class function FromFloat(AValue: Double): TValue;
  public
    class property Name[Index: TTax.TValue]: string read GetName;
    class property AsString[Index: TTax.TValue]: string read GetAsString;
    class property AsFloat[Index: TTax.TValue]: Double read GetAsFloat;
  end;
```

Но результат мне не нравится. Всё равно неудобно (

Можно объявить тип record. И насоздавать констант этого типа. Но они будут разрознены. Перебрать к примеру все элементы - не получится, это ведь не коллекция, не массив

Answer (score 3):

```
type
  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond);
const
  MyTypeNames: array[TMyType] of string = ( 'One', 'Two' );


var
  mt: TMyType;
  str: string;
begin
  mt := mtSecond;
  str := MyTypeNames[mt];
```

---

```
type
  TMyType = (mtFirst, mtSecond);
  TMyTypeInfo = record
    Name: string;
    Value: integer;
  end;
const
  MyTypeInfos: array[TMyType] of TMyTypeInfo = (
    ( Name: 'One'; Value: 123 ),
    ( Name: 'Two'; Value: 456 )
  );


var
  mt: TMyType;
  str: string;
begin
  mt := mtSecond;
  str := MyTypeInfos[mt].Name;
```